# How do I retrieve durations of videos through Youtube API v3 YouTube.PlaylistItems.List request?

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I'm using Youtube API v3 (Java) to access Youtube videos, playlists. Below is a sample code:

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.List request = 
youtube.playlistItems().list("id,contentDetails,snippet");
request.setPlaylistId(/*playlist id*/);                
request.setFields("items(contentDetails/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt, 
snippet/description),nextPageToken,pageInfo");

PlaylistItemListResponse result = request.execute();
```

Now I can get a title of each video from a playlist like this:

```
for (PlaylistItem item : result.getItems()) {
    item.getSnippet().getTitle();
    // But how can I retrieve a duration now?
}
```

I have tried different methods to retrieve duration of the videos, but they all returned null. How do I get a duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video duration can be found inside `contentDetails` part of `.videos().list()`. Unfortunatelly, you cann't get video duration through `PlayListItem` as in your example, you can get only `video_id`.

So, you can extract all `video_id` that playlist has and make an additional call to receive video data, like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=9bZkp7q19f0&part=contentDetails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

as a result, you will get something like:

```
"contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT4M13S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "regionRestriction": {
     "blocked": [
      "DE"
     ]
 }
```

There is a field `duration` inside.

You can play with all YouTube API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: [I found a blog](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video)

```
  for (Video playlistItem : playlistItemList) {
    YouTubeData map = new YouTubeData();

    map.mVideo = playlistItem.getId();
    map.mDuration = Utils.durationToDuration((String) playlistItem.getContentDetails()
        .get("duration"));
    map.mTitle = playlistItem.getSnippet().getTitle();
    map.mDescription = Utils.condenseWhiteSpace(playlistItem.getSnippet().getDescription());
    map.mThumbnail = thumbnailURL(playlistItem.getSnippet().getThumbnails());
    map.mPublishedDate = playlistItem.getSnippet().getPublishedAt().getValue();

    result.add(map);
  }
```